# How to call database name using gremlin like sql? In net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, graph, gremlin, janusgraph

**SQL:**

> String connectionString = "Server=192.168.1.10;Database=exampledb;User Id=testuser;Password=testpass;";
> SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

In which:

- Sever: hostname
- Database: name database
- User: username
- Password: password

**Gremlin**

> var gremlinServer = new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182, true,
> username, password); var gremlinServer = new
> GremlinServer("localhost", 8182);

In which:
The above code does not have a name database, how to create a database name and call it as SQL side?
I want to create and call the database: exampledb

I am using .net core, JanusGraph

Answer (score 3):

You name the graph you want to connect to as an argument to the construction of the `DriverRemoteConnection`:

```
var remoteConnection = new DriverRemoteConnection(new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182)), "mygraph");
var g = Traversal().WithRemote(remoteConnection);
```

You can see here I designate the graph to bind to on the server as "mygraph" (it will normally just default to "g" if nothing is specified.) If you are sending scripts to the server then you would simply use the name of the `TraversalSource` binding in your script, like: `mygraph.V().out()`.

Note that you will need to have "mygraph" already configured in [JanusGraph Server](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.5/basics/server/) (i.e. a repackaging of Gremlin Server with JanusGraph libraries). While Gremlin itself does not have a "CREATE DATABASE" function like SQL, JanusGraph does have a special `GraphFactory` and `GraphManager` that lets you have this sort of behavior - you can read more about that [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/configured-graph-factory/).